# How to detect image tearing/flickering in frame

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am new to OpenCV and Image processing started reading lots of document, and working on problem where I have to process multiple images and needs to detect if any flickering happen. I think relative comparison will not work because we will not have good image all the time.
Hence am looking some way to find thru Pixels intensity analysis or ?? Any suggestion will be appreciated. Note: Am using C++ and OpenCV
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Google motion detection algorithms

Answer (score 0):

I deal with this problem on histogram based approaches. 
The basic idea is to calculate the mean of the 10% darkest pixels and 10% brightest pixels (calculation done on greyscale image).
Let run some test on normal (non flickering images) to determine a "good" value pair. Decide on this value pair if it is flickering or not.

Comment: Thanks John, Any idea if any Licensed tools available to do the Job ?

Comment: Since I dont want to use relative pattern matching, I see problem here to get the "Good value pair" from normal no flickering image (that would be previous image i guess).